# Voting Api + Vote Up / Down = Vote Power

Tags: rating

I have installed VotingApi with Vote Up/Down, also have my own module which implements user exp and levels. I want the voted to be more powerful if the user has greater level. I search through Vote Up/Down files but didnt find a file inserting the vote to databse, so I could change it depending on my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vote will be casted by calling the **Voting api** function `votingapi_set_votes()`. But if you want to change the votes before sending it to `Voting api` there is hook for this called `hook_vud_votes(&$votes)` which you can use.

**Update:**
The api file mentions a hook called `hook_vud_votes(&$votes)` to alter the vote but in their code they are invoking the hook using `drupal_alter()`, so the right hook to implement is `hook_vud_votes_alter(&$votes)`, I think it is mistake in their api doc.

Comment: And the &$votes is an array like in http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!votingapi!votingapi.module/function/votingapi_set_votes/7 but only with one record - the current vote?

Comment: The function accepts an array of votes, a single vote can also be passed. Implement `hook_vud_votes()` and check the `$votes` array structure using `dpm()` function of **Devel** module. Then you can modify it as per your need.

Comment: hook_vud_votes() seems to do not work. Tried by dpm, than also
`function reputation_system_vud_votes(&$votes) {
watchdog('reputation_system','test');
}`
but nothing appears in log.

Comment: @Kretess updated the answer